Incoming email on siteground mailbox using AWS EB and AWS SES
I recently created a subdomain on SiteGround and associated it with an email address. I then updated the CNAME record to point to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, where my web app is hosted, and configured SPF, DMARC, and DKIM on AWS SES to send a large volume of transactional emails.
However, I've stopped receiving emails in my SiteGround mailbox. Could you please explain how I can continue to use the SiteGround mailbox to read incoming emails and send individual responses while using AWS SES (without any specified incoming rules)?
Thank you for your assistance.

Solved changing CNAME to A record (in AWS I got static IP using load balancer Accelerators) and adding MX to subdomain. Regards
